# Store huge json data of indefinite size with key

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, nosql

I need to store the geo path data comprising of geo-points which should be indexed by unique key. For example: The path traveled by vehicle indexed by its trip id. This path can be of indefinite length.

As of now, I am thinking to store the path in the form of JSON object. The options that I have in my mind are `Riak` and `MongoDB`. I want to go with open-source technology. It will be nice if it supports clustering. In case one node goes down, we won't have any downtime in our application.

`MySQL` is currently our source of raw data (which we will be anyhow moving to the NoSQL DB but not as of now). But with the huge amount of data (2 million geo-point entries per day), it takes MYSQL a lot of time to filter the data based on timestamp. MySQL will still be our primary data source. The solution I am looking for will act as a cache for faster path retrieval based on id.

In current MySQL schema, the fields I have are:

```
system_timestamp,
gps_timestamp,
speed,
lat,
lot
```

This table store all the geo-points of the vehicle whether vehicle is on trip or not. Here trip is based on whether driver wants to track the movement or not. If he want to track the movement, we generate a unique trip id and associate it to the driver along with the trip's start time and the end time. Later for displaying the path based on trip id, we use the start & end time of the trip to filter the data from the raw table.

I want to store the trip path into secondary database as a cache so that it's retrieval will be fast.

Which database should be my ideal choice? What other options do I have?

Comment: This seems like an interesting topic, but a few things are not clear to me: 1. How is the data currently being stored in the MySQL database? 2. What exactly are you trying to achieve? It sounds to me like on one hand you are trying to filter by timestamp, but on the other you want to retrieve these entries by ID. 3. What do you actually mean by ID and by "path"?

Comment: Updated the information in the question. I have two table in mysql. One to store the geo points based on timestamp. In the other table I have unique trip id along with the time of start and end of the trip. On selecting the particular trip id, all the geo-points available in between the timestamp should be displayed to the user in the form of path.
I am thinking to cache this path so that I can save retrieval time.

Comment: I'm unclear on what queries you need to perform.  Given trip_id, show path?  Given location, list what vehicles came close to it?  Given timestamp, get vehicle_ids and their locations?  Your question is too detailed on implementation and not detailed enough on the goal(s).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that I believe there is a less complicated way of fixing your performance issue.
I assume you are using MySQL with InnoDB and you are indexing the timestamp field(s).

If I were you, I would simply turn the relevant timestamp (system or gps) into the primary key. With InnoDB, the table data is physically organized to do ultra-fast lookups based on the primary key column(s). Also, make sure that the relevant timestamp column is of the unsigned non-null type.

Now, instead of doing a lookup for the paths in between start and end time (as you're currently doing), I would create a separate table within the same MySQL database containing pairs of trip ID/path timestamp, where "path timestamp" is the primary key from the paths table, as mentioned earlier. Primary index the trip ID. Populate this table using the same logic/mechanism you initially imagined for Riak or MongoDB. This will basically be your "caching" system, using nothing but MySQL.

A typical lookup would take the trip ID to find all of the path timestamps associated and thus all of the path data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paths` (
  `system_timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gps_timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `speed` smallint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `paths` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`system_timestamp`);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trips` (
  `trip_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `system_timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `trips` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`trip_id`);


SELECT * FROM `trips` 
INNER JOIN `paths` ON 
    `trips`.`system_timestamp` = `paths`.`system_timestamp` 
WHERE `trip_id` = 1;
```

Comment: In my case, table can not be indexed based on the timestamp. To give you more insight about our application. Take it as 20,000 cars sending 10 data points every 10 seconds (1 data point per second). This is just the data send by OBD device installed within the car. This data is also sent by driver's mobile at the same rate. Trip's path is the aggregated data from both (between the start time and end time of the trip)

Comment: I understand that the data size is very large and I think it's generally a good idea to denormalize the paths that belong to a certain trip (as you described earlier) in order to improve performance, but what do you aim to accomplish by switching to a NoSQL solution? I think you're problem is not that the technology stack is wrong, but that the index is so large, it's probably several times larger than your buffer pool/machine's RAM. Basically, with the right hardware resources and the right table structure, you can achieve the same in MySQL.

Comment: By the way, apologies for going off-topic, but you could also split your main paths table into smaller tables based on a timestamp-related criteria (e.g. each day has it's own table) and distribute these across several machines. This sharding technique has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Currently I am following the similar approach. But I was looking for some better approach so that we do not have to split the tables. Single table for all. For that `Riak` is a nice choice.

I am not in the favour of  MySQL based on the architecture it works on. MySQL is based relational database model. Since the kind of data I have, I don't need joins on them. And it is structure data. Even I am a huge fan of MySQL, but MySQL is not ideal choice of DB in this case.